# Wrong table formatting for sqlserver grammar

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv

I am using the Laravel query builder for fetching some data from a sqlsrv database. The table I am looking for is `dbo.[Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)]`. Not my choice. The database is developed by an other company.

I keep getting a `General error: 20018 Invalid object name` error when executing my query. I double checked the name for typos but I couldn't find one.

What I did find was a problem in compiling the query. This is my code to test the problem:

```
$query = $connection->query()
    ->from('Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)')
    ->toSql()
```

When I dump the `$query`, I get the following:

`string(67) "select * from [Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot ](Weighbridge)"`

The `]` is in the wrong place here.

This problem keeps existing, even when I'm using the `raw()` helper:

```
$query = $connection->query()
    ->from($connection->raw('dbo.[Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)]'))
    ->toSql()
```

Even in this last example, the `]` moves from the end of the string, to just before the `(`.

Why is this? Am I missing an important rule/mechanic for compiling sqlsrv queries?

The following code does work. That makes it extra weird for me:

`$connection->select('select [Time Slot] as [id] from [Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)]');`

So I think there is something wrong in the `SqlServerGrammar@compileFrom` method. Why does Laravel compile it like this?

Comment: `Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)` is your table name?

Comment: Yes it is. It's an external data source.

Comment: Try to wrap that funny table name with back ticks.

Comment: Doesn't that only work in MySQL?

Comment: Seems so. Test double quotes instead single quotes.

Comment: I already found the problem. It's in the sql server grammar for Laravel. I posted an answer below. I can accept it in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests with xDebug. I found the issue. It's the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammer@wrapTableValuedFunction` method.

Laravel mistakenly sees my table name as a table valued function. That's why the compilation of the query isn't working correctly.

The fix I used for now is a little bit dirty:

```
$query = $connection->query()
    ->from('Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge) as time_slots')
    ->toSql()
```

By adding a alias to the end of my `from` method, the table name get's compiled in an other way. This prevents the table valued function compilation.

I'm not sure if I should report this as a bug. Or if the table name I have to work with simply is invalid.

*Edit: I reported the bug and created a fix. You can find the issue (and PR) [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25895)*

Comment: I will add a link to my PR on Github. I can only accept the answer after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would highly recommend changing the object's name; that is an awful choice. If you can't do this, perhaps create a synonym that is far more "usable". For Example:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.WeighbridgeSlot FOR dbo.[Reukema Blocq Maneschijn BV$Time Slot (Weighbridge)];
```

Then in your application code call the synonym instead:

```
$query = $connection->query()
    ->from('WeighbridgeSlot')
    ->toSql()
```

Comment: I cannot do those things. I also hate the name but it is determined by an external piece of software. Developed by an other company.

Comment: Why can't you create one @MarkWalet ? Although not ideal, you can create a a Synonym in a different database to the onther object; so if you don't have permissions to perform DDL changes in the other database, you could in your own. Otherwise, perhaps you should talk to the other company and get them to sort out their naming conventions; whoever thought of them needs some strong words said to them (in my view).

Comment: I've updated my answer. The raw query does work. But I really want to know why the query builder bugs on this